# How to add a header row to CSV using *this* PHP code?

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am trying to use PHP to generate a CSV file, but I need it to setup a header row and then add the content below the header of the csv.

Right now it starts at line one instead of line two without any header above.

I would like to minimize the modification of this code to do this.

```
$file_open = fopen("report.csv", "a");
    $no_rows = count(file("report.csv"));
    if($no_rows > 1)
    {
        $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
    }
    $form_data = array(
        'sr_no' =>  $no_rows,
        'name'  =>  $name,
        'devicemode'    =>  $devicemode,
        'rating'  =>    $rating,
        'comment'  =>   $comment,
        //'timing'    =>  $diff
    );
    fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
    $name = '';
    $devicemode = '';
    $enhanced = '';
    $comment = ''; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some odd things in the code (why `$no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;`?), but you can easily write out a header row using the keys of `$form_data` with `array_keys()`.

```
$form_data = array(
    'sr_no' =>  $no_rows,
    'name'  =>  $name,
    'devicemode'    =>  $devicemode,
    'rating'  =>    $rating,
    'comment'  =>   $comment,
    //'timing'    =>  $diff
);
if($no_rows == 0)
{
    fputcsv($file_open, array_keys($form_data));
}
```

Comment: With that exact code I no longer get a blank csv file but it containts just the headers not the rest of the input.

Comment: Not sure how the rest of the code is working, you need to add the last 4 rows of code to your existing code (I included the `$form_data` to show where to put the code)

Answer (score 0):

> I forgot that fputcsv takes one line at a time. This code has been updated.

How I would do it is something like this:

```
fputcsv($file_open, array('sr_no', 'name', 'devicemode', 'rating', 'comment'));
fputcsv($file_open, array('sr_no'=>$no_rows, 'name'=>$name, 'devicemode'=>$devicemode, 'rating'=>$rating, 'comment'=>$comment)) ;
```

Comment: I tried that and it just returns a blank csv file.   See  `$file_open = fopen("report.csv", "a");
  $no_rows = count(file("report.csv"));
  if($no_rows > 1)
  {
   $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
  }
   
  fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
   $form_data = array('sr_no', 'name', 'devicemode', 'rating', 'comment') ;
  
   $form_data[] = array('sr_no'=>$no_rows, 'name'=>$name, 'devicemode'=>$devicemode, 'rating'=>$rating, 'comment'=>$comment) ;
 // $name = '';
 // $devicemode = '';
 // $enhanced = '';
 // $comment = ''; `